# How to create ul with links dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created li tag in aspx file in Asp.net C# application like below lines of code

```
            <li id="MenuHome">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="liHome" CssClass="dropdown-toggle" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="Redirect"
                    CommandArgument="~/Home/Home" Text="Home"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:repeater ID="lnkWebPages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lnkWebPages_ItemDataBound">
                <headertemplate>
                    <div class="sub-menu"><ul>
                </headertemplate>
                <itemtemplate>
                    <li>
                        <a href='<%# "~/Default.aspx?PageId=" + Eval("PageId") %>'>'><%#Eval("PageName") %></a>
                    </li>
                </itemtemplate>
            <footertemplate>
                   </ul></div>
            </footertemplate>
            </asp:repeater>
            </li>
```

I have created Web Pages in the table ForumPages in the database like

- PID -    PName - PDescription
- 1  - abc - hello
- 2  -  def - hi
- ... - ... - ...

Now I want that when we click on home page link button, the list of web pages should be displayed in the dropdown and it should be redirected to Default.aspx with page id as parametre in querystring like below

```
      <ul>
      <li><a href="Default.aspx?Pid=1">abc</a></li>
      <li><a href="Default.aspx?Pid=2">def</a></li>
      ...
      </ul>
```

Also I have created function in Business Layer which will fetch page details from table in database.

```
   public ForumPages FetchForumPagesIsPublicTrue()
   {
       ForumPages Item = new ForumPages();
       DbProviderFactory myFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(AppConfiguration.ConnectionStringSettings().ProviderName);
       DbConnection myConnection = myFactory.CreateConnection();
       myConnection.ConnectionString = AppConfiguration.ConnectionStringSettings().ConnectionString;
       try
       {
           DbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
           myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
           myCommand.CommandText = "ForumPagesFetchIsPublicTrue";
           myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           myConnection.Open();
           using (IDataReader dataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (dataReader.Read())
               {
                   Item = GetDataFromReaderForumPages1(dataReader);
               }
           }
           myConnection.Close();
       }
       catch
       {
           myConnection.Close();
       }
       finally
       {
           myConnection.Close();
       }
       return Item;
   }

    public class ForumPages
    {
    public Guid PageId { set; get; }
    public string PageName { set; get; }
    public string PageDescription { set; get; }
    public bool IsPublished { set; get; }
    public bool IsPublic { set; get; }
    public int DisplayOrder { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { set; get; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { set; get; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { set; get; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { set; get; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string SearchHint { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
  }
```

Can anyone tell me how to fetch all these web pages dynamically in repeater control and how to bind these data in repeater control and creating links with query string on page_load() event in aspx.cs file. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you also share the property of this **ForumPages** model class.

Comment: Provided you have a page collection from your database, if you can use datagrid with hyperlink column you should be able to do it much cleaner? Any restrictions for you in that approach?

Comment: I am sorry it cannot be displayed in grid view because i have to display them under "home link" in header section where we display main menu links

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a page collection and assigned it to the listview item source, you can write listview template something like below. Though I have not tested the code but it should give you an idea to start with..

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
             <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="pageLink" NavigateUrl='<%# "Default.aspx?Pid="+ Eval("pageId") %>' Text='<%# Eval("pageName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
             </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateColumn>
```